# Monitoring progress/liveness of background jobs

Tags: shell, java, background-process

I have started a background job. Is there a way to know how it is progressing, and whether it has stopped?

My command line is like:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48  -t data.arff  J48-data.model >&  log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For java processes, use jps command. This would give more information pertaining to the java environment of the java process.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply `tail` the log, which would be useful if the job produces regular output

Or a `ps -ef` will let you know current status of your job (ie whether it is running, finished or in some other state)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Nikhil's Java-specific suggestion of `jps`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27992/monitoring-progress-liveness-of-background-jobs/28006#28006) and [Rory's suggestion to look at the log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27992/monitoring-progress-liveness-of-background-jobs/27994#27994):

You can look for the process in the output of [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) (or [`top`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28Unix%29), which has a crappier UI). You'll see how much CPU time it's currently using.

You can trace the process with [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) (on Linux, or some equivalent such as `trace` or `dtrace` or `ktrace` on other unices): `strace -p1234` where 1234 is the process ID. This will tell you if the process is doing something (which may or may not be something useful) or if it's blocked waiting for input somewhere.